# Creating SSH Certificates for SFTP using a CA

Tags: ssh, certificate, certificate-authority

I'm a bit confused regarding the order of things to make this happen.

This is what I had in mind:

1 - Generate CA public and private key.

2 - Use CA Public Key with SFTP server (TrustedUserCAKeys).

3 - Generate a user private + public key.

4 - Sign user private key using CA.

5 - Connect to the SFTP server using the private key, username and winscp.

Should this work?

Answer (score 3):

CAs sign the public key (producing a certificate). They never see the signee's private key.

Besides that, the workflow seems correct, *except* for the WinSCP part.

The certificates used by TrustedUserCAKeys are a format invented by OpenSSH. Currently no other software supports this kind of certificate authentication – here's the [PuTTY wishlist entry](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh2-openssh-certkeys.html) for them. Because WinSCP uses PuTTY as its SSH core, it **does not** have OpenSSH certificate support, and won't have it until PuTTY does.

Comment: I'm awake of that. It means that I will have to convert the key to a ppk format, which WINSCP offers right out of the box as it detects something else.

Comment: I guess I'll have to give it a go now :) 
Cheers.

Comment: I am not talking about the OpenSSH key format. Converting the key alone gives you nothing, because the client still won't be able to send the _signed certificate_ to the server.

Comment: That sounds strange...
If the conversion is useless then why is it offering it automatically? Better yet, what would it take to do it right?

Comment: It's offering to convert the private key because you're importing the private key. That's a _separate file_ from the certificate that signing produces, and the conversion process will simply ignore the "certificate" part because WinSCP wouldn't know what to do with it. So the server won't know that the keypair was signed.

Comment: So my only solution on Windows is to use a OpenSSH based software? Is there even a such thing?

Comment: @JustAGuy There's [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Dont I need a private key to initiate communication with the SFTP? If I only sign the public key...then what goes?

Comment: @JustAGuy: Both are used simultaneously, in different ways. (You have to send the whole public key, so that the server knows who you are – so the signed certificate needs to be part of that. You also use the private key to compute a proof that you indeed own it. The private key however is never sent anywhere, only used in calculations, so there's no point in signing it.) For more details, you should search "How SSL certificates work" – because the mechanisms are nearly identical.

Comment: Certificates are supported by PuTTY since 0.78 (October 2022) and WinSCP since 6.0 (February 2023).