# Does WinSCP work with OpenSSH SSH certificates?

Tags: ssh, putty, certificate, openssh, winscp

As per [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/public_key), WinScp uses the PuTTy key format, and requires that keys generated by `OpenSSH` be either converted or we use a `/keygen` command line switch.

I wanted to use `SSH certificates` to authenticate the `server`, to solve scalability issues, but this `SSH` certificate is generated by OpenSSH `ssh-keygen`, and I am not sure if certificates generated by this will work fine without issues with `WinSCP` or `WinSCP .NET` libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH certificates is a proprietary non-standard technology.

It was added only recently in PuTTY 0.78 (October 2022).

In WinSCP, it was added in 6.0 beta (February 2023).

---

A related question:
[Creating SSH Certificates for SFTP using a CA](https://superuser.com/q/1375669/213663)

Answer (score 0):

a couple of weeks ago a new version of PuTTY was released which supports OpenSSH certificates: [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/changes.html)
WinSCP will hopefully also supporting OpenSSH certificates, but it's not yet the case
https://winscp.net/tracker/1873
http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32793